# Does there exist such a pentagon that can be covered by a circle?

Tags: calculus, geometry, analysis, inequality

Does there exist a pentagon in which every two nonadjacent vertices
is connected by a diagonal and the minimal height of every triangle formed by the
sides and diagonals of the pentagon whose two sides are the two sides
of the pentagon is strictly greater than $5-\sqrt{5}$, but the pentagon
can be covered by a circle of radius $4$?

Comment: Thanks in advance for any helpful answers!

Comment: From the wording of the question, the answer is no.  There is nothing to stop me making a regular pentagon of side $1000$, which cannot be covered by such a circle.

Comment: Ross, the question is actually about  all pentagons that satisfy the assumption in which the minimal height of every triangle formed by the sides and diagonals of the pentagon whose two sides are the two sides of the pentagon is greater than $5-\sqrt{5}$, is the answer no for all such pentagons that satisfy the assumption? Thanks!

Comment: No I took it to be asking can you cover all such pentagons, so if there is one you cannot cover the answer is no.  A more interesting question is if the maximum height is some number can you cover all pentagons with that description.

Comment: Ross, you might have misunderstood my question, but sorry for the unclearness. I mean, does there exist any such pentagon that can be covered by the circle? Thanks!

Comment: When you say "height of the triangle", do you mean over the diagonal internal to the pentagon as base? Or the minimum of the three heights when you take each side in turn as base?

Comment: @Kundor:  it seems likely to be the same.  The minimum altitude in a triangle is to the longest side to make the area formula work.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to check if any pentagon with the minimal altitude of any triangle is $5-\sqrt 5$ can be covered, the first one to check is a regular pentagon.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon) states that the diagonal of a unit regular pentagon is $\frac 12(1+\sqrt 5)$.  We can drop a perpendicular from the vertex to the diagonal to find the triangle altitude, which is $\frac 1{\sqrt 8}\sqrt{5-\sqrt 5}$.  To have the required altitude, we need a side of $\sqrt 8 \sqrt {5-\sqrt 5}\approx 4.70.$  The radius of the circumscribed circle is then $\sqrt{\frac 2{\sqrt 5-\sqrt 5}}\sqrt 8 \sqrt {5-\sqrt 5}=4$ so it just covers.

Comment: Ross, I actually mean strictly greater than $5-\sqrt{5}$. Do you have an example of a pentagon with the minimal altitude of any triangle strictly greater than $5-\sqrt{5}$ that can be covered? Thanks!

Comment: @Judiae:  I think you can prove not by considering the fact that the corners are on a circle of radius four and two non-neighboring ones have to be no more than $\frac {4\pi}5$ apart.  For a given spacing of the ends of the diagonal, the altitude is maximized by putting the middle point at the middle.  This shows the regular pentagon is the best you can do.

Comment: Ross, how can one exactly or rigorously prove not? Thanks! (If one puts the middle point at the middle, it will affect the minimal altitude of some other triangles.)

Comment: @Judiae:  Just the fact that you have to have two points within $\frac {4\pi}5$ and you can't get the altitude of the triangle with those two points large enough with $r=4$ is enough.  You don't have to look at the other triangles except to justify the $\frac {4\pi}5$  You still have to argue that you can't increase the altitudes by moving points inside the circle, but that seems pretty obvious.

Comment: Ross, the minimal altitude of some other triangles might become less than $5-\sqrt{5}$ if one puts the middle point at the middle.

Comment: @Judiae:  In the regular pentagon, the altitudes are $5-sqrt 5$ and the points are in the middle.  Moving one point from its location will decrease the altitude it is part of, increase one of the others, and decrease another.  If you move it clockwise, the span from it to the point two spaces clockwise decreases.  Then the altitude using that as a base will be less than $5-\sqrt 5$.  The span to the point two behind will increase and so will the altitude.  But if the span is less than $\frac {4\pi}5$ anywhere, the altitude will be less than $5 - \sqrt 5$.  There isn't room for more.

Comment: Ross, I think what you said shows that the minimal altitude in a regular pentagon is local maximum, but it does not show it is a global maximum. How can you show it is a global maximum? Thanks!

Comment: @Judiae:I don't think you are reflecting enough on how close two points must be.  I showed for two points on the circle $\frac {4\pi}5$ apart you can't have an altitude greater than $5-\sqrt 5$ and stay in the circle.  Then if the points are on the circle you must have two within that angle.  It seems obvious, but I have not proved, that moving a point outward will increase the altitude.  The problem is that it will increase the altitude of one and decrease two.  If that is true, the best you can do is have the points on the circle and we are done.

Comment: Ross, thank you for the explanation that may be conceptual, but it still needs a rigorous and complete proof. So can you prove it? Thanks!